# [ Bison ]Is it possible to customize runtime data dir or specify a relatif path in config of compilation?

Tags: compilation, bison

I am doing the build local of Bison(Linux), to provide it to other team to use. 
I need to download its source from homepage and build it local, then install etc... but problem is that, after we build it(its lib/bin ..), the user of it need to use it at other pc(rather than the same host than us).
I notice that, at the build/install for Bison, we need to specify the path like datarootdir etc for the .configure, which provides an absolute path into the build and which used later in runtime for binary of Bison. (dir inside 'Share' for instance).
But since this path in build we specified would be different from the people(user)'s host's real dir. (the lib/bin are rsync later to other ppl's pc) Then this path of my local would not work for them.

My question is that, is it possible  to specify a relatif path while compile/install Bison,(for example relatif to Bison binary etc). Or while using the binary of Bison, is it possible to customize the datadir etc for it?
So this could be more flexible at the user side later? if else we have to provide the same dir structure exact the runtime onw as the built one.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 2):

You can override the *data path* with the following:

```
BISON_PKGDATADIR=/some/other/path/share/bison
```

Comment: thanks! I was in a situation similar to vivi's and this has saved the day!